# How to import table into an existing table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with identical structures. Let's call them table A and B.

Table A consists of records with ID as primary key from 1-10 and B has the table with IDs 11-20.

Given I have imported table A into mysql table, how can I, in a way, concatenate table B to A?

Any thoughts will be much appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

You use `insert`:

```
insert into tablea
    select *
    from tableb;
```

It is better to list the columns for the `insert` and `select`, but you can do it with this syntax if the tables really do have identical formats.